# remove/replace specific HTML from inside iframe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Okay so in my page I have an iframe element which will load HTML that will always have a specific line of HTML code in it that I need to replace when the iframe is loaded. The iframe src will vary so it has to be done as the iframe is loaded. The HTML I want to replace is in the file that's loaded by the iframe and it will look something like this:

```
<div class="myclass1" style="height:XXXpx; width:YYYpx;">
```

So what I need is actually for every div that has class="myclass1" to have the height attribute of the style stripped and the width kept whatever it was. All "myclass1" divs will follow this format. So I want to replace all lines like that with this:

```
<div class="myclass1" style="width:YYYpx;">
```

I'm not very experienced with javascript at all really so any help, even just pointers, is appreciated because I don't know how to start of even if this is possible.

Comment: unless the src of the iframe is on the same exact domain, you can't, according to Same Origin Policy

Answer (score 1):

If the src of the iframe is on the same domain, use this :

```
var iFrame = document.getElementById("your-iframe-id");
if ( iFrame.contentDocument ) 
{
   iFrameDocument = iFrame.contentDocument;
}
else if ( iFrame.contentWindow ) 
{ 
  iFrameDocument = iFrame.contentWindow.document;
}
```

The use `iFrameDocument.getElementById` or whatever you need

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following example for change the styles of loaded div,Call the javascript function after loading the page .

```
      <html>
       <head>
       <script type="text/javascript">
       function change_style()
        {
          document.getElementById("div_id").style.width="yyypx";
        }  
       </script> 
       </head>
       <body>

        <div  id="div_id" class="myclass1" style="height:XXXpx; width:YYYpx;">
          -------------------
          -------------------
         </div>

      <script>
       change_style();
      </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```